# Regex does not seem to work

Tags: java, regex

I have a problem with the regex commands:

```
text="blue:{allocatable,allocate,assign,"
String patternblue = ".*blue.*";
boolean isMatchblue = Pattern.matches(patternblue, text.toString());
System.out.println(isMatchblue);
```

gives "`false`", what happens?

PS: text has been built up with `StringBuilder()`

Edit: I checked the other posts in the forum but I don't get it working neither with .*? nor ?s

Any input? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure this is the text content? Because for me this results in `true`

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem with current code. Please post proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) / [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You might want to debug the value of `text`, since if it contains the value you have shown this should be working.

Comment: Does your `text` contain few lines (in other words, does it contain line separators - remember that `.` doesn't match them by default)?

Comment: Yes, it is actually extracted from a file